# Zip PDF-Files download not working

Tags: php, cakephp, php-ziparchive

I'm building an interface that allows collecting PDF-Files from a server-path to download them zipped at once which works fine most of the time. Now, some PDF-Files are not working, means if the zip contains one of the non-working files the whole download will not performed.

Now i tried *many* files with different sizes. I can tell most of the files larger than 10MB are not working, but one file (15mb) is working, so it can't be the file-size causing this error - right?

What happens is there's just no download at all. Additionally tried reading the results of "$zip->addFile" and "$zip->close" but it's all true, even if the download will not be performed. ANY ideas which may cause this bug or at least some hints on how to find this out?

The (x)debug inspection of the variables during process does not differ between the time it worked and the time its not working. Only differences are filesizes and -paths.

**Here's the Code i'm using to build the ZIP:**

```
public function downloadFiles() {
        $myFiles = $this->Session->read('Files.MyFiles');
        if(count($myFiles)) {
            // build zip
            $zipname = 'amaz_photos_' . time() . '.zip';
            $zip = new ZipArchive();
            $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
            foreach($myFiles as $file) {
                if($file['type'] == 'directory') {
                    $dirName = str_replace('/', '', substr($file['path'], strrpos($file['path'], '/'), (strlen($file['path']) - strrpos($file['path'], '/'))));
                    $zip->addEmptyDir($dirName);
                    $this->addFolderToZip($file['path'] . '/', $zip, $dirName . '/');
                } else {
                    $zip->addFile($file['path'], str_replace('/', '', substr($file['path'], strrpos($file['path'], '/'), (strlen($file['path']) - strrpos($file['path'], '/')))));
                }
            }
            $zip->close();
            // get(send) zip
            header('Content-Type: application/zip');
            header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $zipname);
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
            readfile($zipname);
            ignore_user_abort(true);
            unlink($zipname);
        }

        // clear "myFiles"
        //$this->Session->write('Files.MyFiles', array());

        $this->redirect(array(
            'controller' => 'pages',
            'action' => 'display'
        ));
    }
```

After all i tried opening the affected files with several PDF-Readers including Adobe's original to determine if its broken, but ̶i̶̶t̶̶s̶  it seems not.

**This will occur in openable zip-files but the download does not start anyways. I found out that in that special cases where the download does not start, there is no response-header ("application/zip") being set on the network-frame compared to the times it worked.**

What I found out else:
Lets say I have a folder with 20 files in it, that's not downloading. I tried selecting file 1-10: downloading, then I tried downloading file 11-20: downloading, then I tried to download file 1-20: not downloading, then I tried two times mixing the patterns, first the even files 2,4,6,8.. (1-20), after that the odd files 1,3,5,7,.. (1-20): each not downloading.
This states out t**he error does not belong to a specific file**.

Any suggestions how to determine the trigger for this error?

---

> Update:
>
> I was able to download the generated zip-file doing these steps:
>
> 1. Trigger 'create & download zip-file'
> 2. It creates a zip-file but not download it
> 3. Type the generated zip-files filename in the code to download it on the next procedure (e. g. "$zipname = "generatedOnStep1.zip").
> 4. Trigger 'create & download zip-file' again
> 5. It does not download the (recently) generated file, but the file i generated in step 1. So it seems that: Generating Zip-Files is working AND downloading that same zip-File is working, but not at once and only in some unknown combinations.

...

> Update 2:
>
> Since I was not able to determine the issue nor fix it, I ended up redesigning the whole process, to redirect to the generated zip-file instead of "readfile" it. Some features had to be sourced out but anyways it works this way.

Comment: Have you tried checking the size of the pdf files inside the zip? Do they have a size? what is the size compared to the original files. Also you didnt give us the code for addFolderToZip.

Comment: The addFolderToZip() is not used in this case, due to single files being added. Just skip in mind. Anyways you brought me to the idea not to drop the file after downloading it. The PDF can be viewed the size is 2MB larger then the not-zipped one. So it seems everything is working fine but the download does not start. I have large video-files which can be downloaded, so i'm pretty sure its not about any memory-limits. Also the HDD Space is quite empty (enough).

Comment: Just to be clear: The ZIP is generated correctly, can be oppened and the PDF can be viewed. But the Download is not starting (only) with specific PDFs.

Comment: How often does this happen, have you tried not deleting the generated zip files to see what is actually inside the zip files or if they were actually created? Have you checked for php timeouts (run time limit or memory limit?). The no download, do you get a blank page(might indicate an error)? If so check error log of php / the webserver. (btw, time() is only unique per second, be careful with this, if 2 requests are done at the same time it might cause issues. Perhaps try [tempnam](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php)).

Comment: Yes i tried keeping the files. This will occur in openable zip-files but the download does not start anyways. I found out that in that special cases where the download does not start, there is no response-header ("application/zip") being set on the network-frame compared to the times it worked. Log is empty.

Comment: what cakephp version?

Comment: I solved the problem by redirecting to the zip-file instead of "readfile" it or something like that. This splits lots of logic but works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this... Remove `readfile($zipname);` and replace it with these:

```
/* make sure no other functions
holding this file */
$filehandle = fopen($zipname, "r");

while (!feof($filehandle)) {
  /* lets read the file by pieces and
  send it to user's browser */
  echo fread($filehandle, 8192);
}

fclose($filehandle);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It results in the same behaviour. If i zip manually, it downloads the zip, if i zip by zipArchive, it creates the zip, but does not download.. somewhat of non-deterministic miracle is going on here..

Comment: Even if your answer did not solve my problem it brought me to redesign the process, by redirecting to the file after creating the zip. Thanks for the prod.

Comment: Thanks... Let me know if you solved your problem... I saw that your question was updated. I'll investigate further based on your updates and let you know.